# How to write regex for verifying a string between [1,65535]

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a regular expression which shoud verify the strings which are in range [1,65535]
This is what I have tried, but it didn't work

```
^([1-9]|[12]\d|6553[0-5])$
```

Please help me to get the right regex

Comment: See http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/

Comment: You don't need a regex for this. Convert the numeric string into number and check if it is in the range `1 - 65535` using `<=` and `>=` operators